# how to add a set of SOS1 constraint in pyomo

Tags: linear-programming, pyomo, mixed-integer-programming

I am solving an optimization problem where I need to assign a carton type to every product, and determine how many cartons of the corresponding type should be used. Every product can be assigned to only 1 carton type. How many units of a specific product a carton of a specific type can hold is known.

I have created decision variables as follows:

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo
model = pyo.ConcreteModel(name="Pack_size_optim")
model.dv_prod_carton = pyo.Var(prod, cartons, within=pyo.NonNegativeIntegers)
```

prod, cartons are the lists having unique products and carton types

Now, for my problem, what I want is decision variables : for each product across all carton types should be a SOS 1 set, i.e. for every product only one carton type should have > 0 value.

I was trying something like below, but it is not working :

```
for i in prod:    
    pyo.SOSConstraint(var = [model.dv_prod_carton[i, j] for j in cartons], sos = 1)
```

I think var argument in the pyo.SOSConstraint function above should be an 'IndexedVar', but instead I have a list of variables.

Can anybody please help me in what I am trying to achieve above. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are (at least) four ways to model this:

- SOS1. Pyomo has support for SOS1 variables: https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/library_reference/kernel/sos.html.
- Binary variables with big-M constraints. This is the most portable (over different solvers) but requires good bounds. I use this when possible.
- Binary variables with indicator constraints.
- Disjunctive programming. This is probably a bit of overkill for this case. Pyomo has support for this: https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/contributed_packages/gdpopt.html

I was able to get SOS1 variables to work by explicitly specifying .ref and .sosno suffices. I am sure there are better ways, but at least this seems to work:

```
# SOS1 test with concrete model

import pyomo.environ as pyo

model = pyo.ConcreteModel()

model.x = pyo.Var([1,2], domain=pyo.PositiveReals, bounds=(0,1))

model.OBJ = pyo.Objective(expr = model.x[1] + model.x[2],sense=pyo.maximize)

# don't exactly know how to get these approaches to work
#pyomo.core.kernel.sos.sos1([model.x[1],model.x[2]])
#pyo.SOSConstraint(var = [model.x[1], model.x[2]], sos = 1)
#model.sos_constraint = pyo.SOSConstraint(var = model.x, sos = 1)
#Message: Solver does not support SOS level 1 constraints 

model.sosno = pyo.Suffix(direction=pyo.Suffix.EXPORT)
model.ref = pyo.Suffix(direction=pyo.Suffix.EXPORT)

# Add entry for each index of model.x
model.sosno.set_value(model.x, 1)
model.ref[model.x[1]] = 1
model.ref[model.x[2]] = 2

# if SOS1 works correctly solution should have one of x[1],x[2] nonzero
# indeed we see with Cplex:
# 'Objective': {'OBJ': {'Value': 1.0}}, 'Variable': {'x[1]': {'Value': 1.0}}
```

This is a bit as you would do this in AMPL.

Answer (score 0):

You're going down the wrong path here.  You don't need (and shouldn't use) a Special Ordered Set here.

Fair disclosure:  I've never used them, perhaps somebody else has an opinion as to why they would fit here.  But in your case, You will have multiple assignments of products-cartons, so I can't see how you would fit this.

You just need to do 2 things...

1. declare a binary decision variable to be indexed by 2 sets:  products, containers to represent the decision to put product `p` in container `c`.  this will be the basis of your model
2. set up a constraint that sums over all containers for each product and set it to <= 1

... then whatever other constraints/obj as necessary

Comment: The way I had set up my problem, I am determining right number of cartons for each product. Let's say I have 1 prod - P1, and 3 carton types - C1, C2, C3, and they can hold 5,6,7 units of P1.  The way I have set up my problem is to determine right number (and hence the corresponding carton type) cartons reqd. 
So, for e.g. output could look like P1 -> C1 = 0, P1 -> C2 = 0, P1 -> C3 = 5. With this I can identify the carton type (C3) and number of cartons both
I understand your solution, but then I would need extra decision variables to get to the right number of cartons i.e. 5 (C3).

Comment: Yes.  I agree completely, and that is a standard way of doing this type of problem.  You'll need one binary decision variable to represent the decision to use C3, which would be something like `use[p, c]` and a second integer variable to represent the quantity, indexed similarly, `qty[p, c]`.

Comment: ....  comment back if that doesn't make sense and I can augment my answer above w/ example

Comment: Understand. However, number of prods are large, and the set of unique carton types are also large. In your approach I will be making 2 matrices of decision variables index by p, c. And in case, I need to multiply these 2 decision variables, then I would need to linearize the product of binary, integer varbs. 
This will require more auxillary varbs getting introduced.

By declaring relevant set of decision varbs as SOS1 set, we can avoid making binary varbs, thereby reducing the number of varbs. AND i want to learn how to declare SOS1 in pyomo as well :) Thanks for your inputs though

Comment: OK on all.  A few notes...  the matrices made above are very sparse, and this is a pretty standard approach.  No multiplication of variables is required...it is linear.  Good luck!